# if statement on multiline string not working

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm trying to force the restart of my rsyslog server. I have sanitary reboot during the day, and sometimes the restart fails, so I want to restart it until the restart is a success.

At this point I'm trying to check if the output of the restart matches the output it is supposed to give when the restart is good.

But I don't understand why the `if` statement below doesn't work. It always goes to the else statement whether I put a `==` or `!=` in the test condition.

Is there a way to check if a multi-line string is equal to another predefined multi-line string?

```
#!/bin/sh
endv=0
testv="Shutting down system logger: [  OK  ]
Starting system logger: [  OK  ]"
startv="$(/etc/init.d/rsyslog restart)"

while [ $endv == 0 ]; do
        echo "$startv"
            if [[ "$startv" != "$testv" ]]; then
               startv="$(/etc/init.d/rsyslog restart)"
                echo THEN
            else
                echo ELSE
                endv=1
            fi
done
```

Comment: AFAIK it should work... in `bash` - however `/bin/sh` is not `bash` on Ubuntu systems (and doesn't support the `[[ ... ]]` extended test). However I would avoid string tests if possible - doesn't the init script return an exit code?

Comment: Also, are you sure rsyslog outputs to stdout?

Comment: For the first question I'll have to check
For the second, yes, when I check with     echo "$startv"  I get the result I'm expecting :

Comment: `[ a == b ]` is also not standard, and `dash` doesn't support it. Use a single `=` for string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

*A few preliminaries:*

1. You should probably be moving away from invoking SysV init scripts directly; you are at least one and likely two steps behind the curve ( SysV init was replaced by `upstart` and then by `systemd`). For example:

   ```
   systemctl restart rsyslog.service
   ```
2. Whichever init interface you use, it's likely that you can use the command's `EXIT_STATUS` directly rather than capturing its output and testing string equality. For example:

   ```
   systemctl restart rsyslog.service
   if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
     ...
   fi
   ```

   (in any case, as @choroba poined out in comments, the '[OK]' message may in fact be going to standard error rather than standard output).
3. In Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` is not `bash`: see [DashAsBinSh](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh). Among other things, that means it won't support the `[[ . . . ]]` extended test syntax.

---

Having got those out of the way, `bash` does indeed support string equality tests on multiline strings e.g.

```
$ str1='This is
a string'
$ str2='That is
a string'
$ str3='This is
a string'
$
$ [[ "$str1" != "$str1" ]] && echo "No match" || echo "Match"
Match
$ [[ "$str1" != "$str2" ]] && echo "No match" || echo "Match"
No match
$ [[ "$str1" != "$str3" ]] && echo "No match" || echo "Match"
Match
```